# How does the Unix utility "sed" read the nth line of a file?

Tags: file, unix, io

I want to know what happens under the hood. In order to distinguish *nth* line from the *(n-1)th*, you need to read the contents of the file from disk, and decode it as per an encoding scheme (ASCII/UTF-8) to get the "new line" characters. However, if the length of a particular line is unbounded, this will involve reading the entire file in the worst case. Yet, *sed* and similar tools are able to achieve a very good performance.

What am I missing here? Is there a faulty assumption in my description of how these tools read the *nth* line?

Comment: Only the `sed` interface is somewhat standardized (in Posix). The implementations may be very different. To count lines you usually only need to count the newlines and that's not very hard.

Comment: For GNU sed, check [its repo](https://savannah.gnu.org/git/?group=sed).

Comment: Source code: git clone git://git.sv.gnu.org/sed